# LiveData Transformation to StateFlow / SharedFlow

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

What is the equivalent code for this live data transformation in StateFlow / SharedFlow?

```
val myLiveData: LiveData<MyLiveData> = Transformations
                    .switchMap(_query) {
                        if (it == null) {
                           AbsentLiveData.create()
                        } else {
                           repository.load()
                     }
```

Basically, I want to listen to every query changes to react what to return. So, anything similar to that using StateFlow / SharedFlow is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

First, create an helper extension function:

```
fun <R> Flow<R>.toStateFlow(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope, initialValue: R) = stateIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, initialValue)
```

---

Use `mapLatest{}` for `Transformations.map()`:

```
val studentNames = _students.mapLatest { students ->
    students.map { "${it.name}" }
}.toStateFlow(uiScope, emptyList())    //uiScope is viewModelScope
```

Use `flatMapLatest{}` for `Transformations.switchMap()`:

```
val asteroids = _asteroidFilter.flatMapLatest { filter ->
    asteroidRepository.getAsteroidsFlow(filter)
}.toStateFlow(uiScope, emptyList())
```

Use `combine()` for `MediatorLiveData`:

```
val sumScore = combine(_team1Score, _team2Score) { score1, score2 ->
    score1 + score2
}.toStateFlow(uiScope, 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

`switchMap` is deprecated in `flows` and should use either of `flatMap`, `transform` or `transformLatest` to convert one type of flows to others. An example for that would be

```
val myFlow = flowOf<Int>().transform<Int, String> { flowOf("$it") }}
```

I guess you can use same logic for `StateFlow` or `SharedFlows`.